# Auto scroll down to next element

Tags: javascript, scroll, dojo

I am trying to make an RSS feed for the customers of our website to see news at.
The idea is that I want to have a slow and smooth downward scroll animation just for the purpose of revieling the news not shown in the visible div element.
The element that contains all these articles has a set height and has its own vertical scrollbar.
The articles are height:100px;width:100% and have their unique id, but there are everything from 1 to 100 articles shown depending on the RSS feeds.

How can I make a pure javascript that does this task?
I am also using dojo in case they have a way of doing this that I don't know about.

It is all javascript generated HTML.
I will post a summary of the structure for reference.

Thanks.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="mainLeft">
    <div id="slider1_container" />
    <div id="rssBoxWrapper">
        <table id="rssBoxHeader" />
    <div id="newsContentWrapper">  <!--Contains scroll bar & articles -->
        <table id="article0" />``
        <table id="article1" />
        <table id="article2" />
        <table id="article3" />
        <table id="article4" /> <!-- Houndres of articles follows.. -->
```

Comment: Have a look at [this link](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: I actually got it to work making just timeouts and intervals, but I will concider fullPage in the future, it looks like a very neat way to beautifully animate the site, but I cba trying to implement it at the final stage of the webpage.
Thanks though!